# SwipeView iOS library views out of order/duplicated

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, swipeview

I'm using the SwipeView library to create a series of swipeable webview (https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView).

After swiping back and forth a few times, the webviews are displayed out of order, and sometimes duplicated (item in position 1 is a duplicate of item in position 3, etc.)

There was a similar problem on github (https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView/issues/40) but I think I'm setting up the reused view correctly.

```
- (UIView *)swipeView:(SwipeView *)swipeView viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIWebView *webView = (UIWebView *) view;
    if (webView == nil) {
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:swipeView.frame];

        UIRefreshControl *rControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
        [rControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [webView.scrollView addSubview:rControl];

    }

    webView.delegate = self;
    NSString *strURL = _urls[index];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    return webView;
}
```

from debugger: (notice how _itemViews is out of order)

```
_itemViews  __NSDictionaryM *   4 key/value pairs   0x08e5ce20
[0] (null)  (int)0 : (no summary)   
[1] (null)  (int)3 : (no summary)   
[2] (null)  (int)1 : (no summary)   
[3] (null)  (int)2 : (no summary)

_urls   __NSArrayM *    @"4 objects"    0x14d9ca00
[0] __NSCFConstantString *  @"http://cmcewen.ngrok.com/links/new"   0x000eac50
[1] __NSCFConstantString *  @"http://cmcewen.ngrok.com/users/sign_in"   0x000eac60
[2] __NSCFString *  @"http://cmcewen.ngrok.com/links/178"   0x14e49630
[3] __NSCFString *  @"http://cmcewen.ngrok.com/links/178/comments"  0x14e4d510
```

Comment: What is `_itemViews`? It looks like an `NSDictionary` but I suspect it's supposed to be an array. Show the code where you create that and use it.

Comment: I don't ever use it - it's part of the SwipeView source: https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView/blob/b9a4eb777b9b50504247bb9d80fbf9e7977f6da9/SwipeView/SwipeView.m